# JS/CSS: Bind together number input's function with resizable element's function

Tags: javascript, html, css, typography

I'm working on a little typography app and have hit a blocker. I've extracted to core code into a pen, i.e., there are other inputs, buttons in the UI. Hence, why I'm using querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]'), etc.

Goal is for the draggable element to update the text measure (line length) and BIND to the number input, by updating the CSS prop:
`--_typecsset-text-measure`

I have a resize observer logging the draggable element to console but I'm way out of my depth at this point!

I set up a Pen: https://codepen.io/timpish/full/abMdBay

```js
// font, leading, measure (line length) input resizers
        const numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
        function updateProp(event) {
            const uom = this.dataset.uom || '';
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--_${this.name}`, this.value + uom);
        }
        numberInputs.forEach((input, index) => {
            input.addEventListener('input', updateProp);
        });

        // measure drag (.resizable) an update #measure
        let observeMeasure = new ResizeObserver(function (mutations) {
            const sizeInRem = mutations[0].contentRect.width / parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize); document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--_typecsset-text-measure', sizeInRem + 'rem');
            const input = document.getElementById('measure');
            input.value = sizeInRem.toFixed(1);
        });
        let drag = document.querySelector(".resizable");
        observeMeasure.observe(drag);
```

```css
/* globals */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:not(main p) {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:where(html) {
  --_typecsset-body-fontSize: var(--typecsset-base-fontSize, 1rem);
  --_typecsset-body-lineHeight: var(--typecsset-base-lineHeight, 1.5);
  --_typecsset-color-dark: var(--typecsset-color-dark, hsl(0, 0%, 0%));
  --_typecsset-color-light: var(--typecsset-color-light, hsl(0, 0%, 100%));
  --_typecsset-color-neutral: var(--typecsset-color-neutral, hsl(0, 0%, 50%));
  --_typecsset-recursive-caslAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-caslAxis,
    "CASL" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis,
    "CRSV" 0.5
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-monoAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-monoAxis,
    "MONO" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-slntAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-slntAxis,
    "slnt" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis,
    "wght" 400
  );
  --_typecsset-text-measure: var(--typecsset-text-measure, 80rem);
  font-variation-settings: var(--_typecsset-recursive-monoAxis),
    var(--_typecsset-recursive-caslAxis), var(--_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis),
    var(--_typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis), var(--_typecsset-recursive-slntAxis);
  font-family: Recursive, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--_typecsset-color-light);
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-dark);
    margin-top: 1rem !important;
}

#measure {
    inline-size: var(--_typecsset-text-measure);
    /* width: var(--_typecsset-text-measure); */
}

/* dark mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--_typecsset-color-dark);
    color: var(--_typecsset-color-light);
  }
}

main {
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-size: var(--_typecsset-body-fontSize);
  line-height: var(--_typecsset-body-lineHeight);
}

/* elements */
h2,
h4,
input,
main {
  padding-left: 0.2rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.2rem !important;
}

input {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  line-height: 0.9 !important;
}

h2,
h4 {
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral) !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

h2 {
  /* 'cap' unit for capital letters. Safari's jank. */
  letter-spacing: 0.06cap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  --_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis,
    "wght" 600
  );
  font-variation-settings: var(--_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis);
}

/* sub header below inputs/buttons */
h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}

/* drag */
h4 + h4 {
  color: currentColor !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

input {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  border-top: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-bottom: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* box-shadow: inset 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 var(--_typecsset-color-neutral) */
  padding: ;
}

/* blockquote inside main */
blockquote {
  hanging-punctuation: first last;

  &::before {
    content: "\201C";
  }

  &::after {
    content: "\201D";
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  }
}

/* layout primitives */

.center {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-inline: auto;
  max-inline-size: var(--_typecsset-text-measure);
  padding-inline-start: 1rem;
  padding-inline-end: 1rem;
}

.cluster {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--space, 0.618rem);
  /* use scale */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-ruler {
  background-image: url("icons.svg#icon-ruler-view");
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 3.1rem 1rem;
}

.rhythm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

[class^="rhythm"] > * {
  margin-block: 0;
}

.rhythm-xs > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.2rem;
}

.rhythm-s > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.309rem;
}

.rhythm-m > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.618rem;
}

.rhythm-l > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 1.236rem;
}

.rhythm-xl > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 1.857rem;
}

/* utils */
.typeface-alegreya {
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
}

.color\:neutral {
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
}

.cursor\:crosshair {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.resizable {
  resize: inline;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.width\:100\% {
  width: 100% !important;
}

/*debugger */
* {
  outline: cornflowerblue dotted 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<body class="center">

  <nav class="rhythm-m">

    <section class="resizable">
      <label class="rhythm-xs">
        <h2>Text Measure</h2>
        <input id="measure" class="icon-ruler steppers-none" type="number" value="80" step="1" min="10" max="150" data-uom="rem" name="typecsset-text-measure">
        <div class="cluster">
          <h4>rem</h4>
          <h4>drag&nbsp;&searr;&nbsp;</h4>
        </div>
      </label>
    </section>
    
  </nav>

  <main class="typeface-alegreya">
    <p>
    <blockquote>The density of texture in a written or types<span title="45th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span>et page is called it<span title="66th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span>s <em>color</em>.<span title="75th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span> This has nothing to do with red or green ink; it refers only to the darkness or blackness of the letterforms in mass. Once the demands of legibilty and logical order are satisfied, <em>eveness of color</em> is the typographer's normal aim. And color depends on four things: the design of the type, the spacing between the letters, the spacing between the words, and the spacing between the lines. None is independent of the others.</blockquote>
    </p>
    <p>
    <blockquote>Anything from <em>45 to 75</em> characters is widely regarded as a satisfactory length of line for a single-column page set in a serifed text face in a text size. The 66-character line (counting both letters and spaces) is widely regarded as ideal. For multiple column work, a better average is 40 to 50 characters.</blockquote>
    </p>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the future, please include the code as a snippet or code block in the question. External links are helpful but are prone to break, meaning the question won't be useful to future readers.

Comment: There is a code snippet embedded, Sir. See "Show code snippet" under the Pen ink.

Comment: I added that...? Can't tell if that was a joke or not lol

Comment: Apologies! I didn't  know others could edit the original post. Will embed code henceforth. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update the CSS variable to the width of the draggable element in px:

```js
let observeMeasure = new ResizeObserver(function (mutations) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    "--_typecsset-text-measure",
     mutations[0].contentRect.width + "px"
  );
});
```

Demo:

```js
// font and lead resizers
const numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
//const measure = document.getElementById("measure");
//const labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');

function updateProp(event) {
  const uom = this.dataset.uom || "";
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    `--_${this.name}`,
    this.value + uom
  );
  //const label = labels[Array.from(rangeSliders).indexOf(this)];
  //label.textContent = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(3);
}
numberInputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", updateProp);
  //labels[index].textContent = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(3);
});

// measure (line length)
let observeMeasure = new ResizeObserver(function (mutations) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    "--_typecsset-text-measure",
     mutations[0].contentRect.width + "px"
  );
});
let drag = document.querySelector(".resizable");
observeMeasure.observe(drag);
```

```css
/* globals */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:not(main p) {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:where(html) {
  --_typecsset-body-fontSize: var(--typecsset-base-fontSize, 1rem);
  --_typecsset-body-lineHeight: var(--typecsset-base-lineHeight, 1.5);
  --_typecsset-color-dark: var(--typecsset-color-dark, hsl(0, 0%, 0%));
  --_typecsset-color-light: var(--typecsset-color-light, hsl(0, 0%, 100%));
  --_typecsset-color-neutral: var(--typecsset-color-neutral, hsl(0, 0%, 50%));
  --_typecsset-recursive-caslAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-caslAxis,
    "CASL" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis,
    "CRSV" 0.5
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-monoAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-monoAxis,
    "MONO" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-slntAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-slntAxis,
    "slnt" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis,
    "wght" 400
  );
  --_typecsset-text-measure: var(--typecsset-text-measure, 80rem);
  font-variation-settings: var(--_typecsset-recursive-monoAxis),
    var(--_typecsset-recursive-caslAxis), var(--_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis),
    var(--_typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis), var(--_typecsset-recursive-slntAxis);
  font-family: Recursive, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--_typecsset-color-light);
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-dark);
}

/* dark mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--_typecsset-color-dark);
    color: var(--_typecsset-color-light);
  }
}

main {
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-size: var(--_typecsset-body-fontSize);
  line-height: var(--_typecsset-body-lineHeight);
}

/* elements */
h2,
h4,
input,
main {
  padding-left: 0.2rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.2rem !important;
}

input {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  line-height: 0.9 !important;
}

h2,
h4 {
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral) !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

h2 {
  /* 'cap' unit for capital letters. Safari's jank. */
  letter-spacing: 0.06cap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  --_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis,
    "wght" 600
  );
  font-variation-settings: var(--_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis);
}

/* sub header below inputs/buttons */
h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}

/* drag */
h4 + h4 {
  color: currentColor !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

input {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  border-top: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-bottom: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* box-shadow: inset 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 var(--_typecsset-color-neutral) */
  padding: ;
}

/* blockquote inside main */
blockquote {
  hanging-punctuation: first last;

  &::before {
    content: "\201C";
  }

  &::after {
    content: "\201D";
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  }
}

/* layout primitives */

.center {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-inline: auto;
  max-inline-size: var(--_typecsset-text-measure);
  padding-inline-start: 1rem;
  padding-inline-end: 1rem;
}

.cluster {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--space, 0.618rem);
  /* use scale */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-ruler {
  background-image: url("icons.svg#icon-ruler-view");
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 3.1rem 1rem;
}

.rhythm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

[class^="rhythm"] > * {
  margin-block: 0;
}

.rhythm-xs > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.2rem;
}

.rhythm-s > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.309rem;
}

.rhythm-m > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.618rem;
}

.rhythm-l > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 1.236rem;
}

.rhythm-xl > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 1.857rem;
}

/* utils */
.typeface-alegreya {
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
}

.color\:neutral {
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
}

.cursor\:crosshair {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.resizable {
  resize: inline;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.width\:100\% {
  width: 100% !important;
}

/*debugger */
* {
  outline: cornflowerblue dotted 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<body class="center">

  <nav class="rhythm-m">

    <section class="resizable">
      <label class="rhythm-xs">
        <h2>Measure</h2>
        <input id="measure" class="width:100% icon-ruler steppers-none" type="number" value="80" step="1" min="10" max="150" data-uom="rem" name="typecsset-text-measure">
        <div class="cluster">
          <h4>rem</h4>
          <h4>drag&nbsp;&searr;&nbsp;</h4>
        </div>
      </label>
    </section>
  </nav>

  <main class="typeface-alegreya">
    <p>
    <blockquote>The density of texture in a written or types<span title="45th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span>et page is called it<span title="66th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span>s <em>color</em>.<span title="75th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span> This has nothing to do with red or green ink; it refers only to the darkness or blackness of the letterforms in mass. Once the demands of legibilty and logical order are satisfied, <em>eveness of color</em> is the typographer's normal aim. And color depends on four things: the design of the type, the spacing between the letters, the spacing between the words, and the spacing between the lines. None is independent of the others.</blockquote>
    </p>
    <p>
    <blockquote>Anything from <em>45 to 75</em> characters is widely regarded as a satisfactory length of line for a single-column page set in a serifed text face in a text size. The 66-character line (counting both letters and spaces) is widely regarded as ideal. For multiple column work, a better average is 40 to 50 characters.</blockquote>
    </p>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

---

To convert to rem and set the input to the same value:

```js
let observeMeasure = new ResizeObserver(function (mutations) {
  const sizeInRem =
    mutations[0].contentRect.width /
    parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    '--_typecsset-text-measure',
    sizeInRem + 'rem'
  );

  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  input.value = sizeInRem;
});
```

Obviously you'll have to figure out how to actually get a reference to the input instead of just querying for the first one, but this should give you the idea. I'm guessing you'll also want to set the draggable element's size when updating the input, which I'm sure you can figure out.

Demo:

```js
// font and lead resizers
const numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
//const measure = document.getElementById("measure");
//const labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');

function updateProp(event) {
  const uom = this.dataset.uom || "";
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    `--_${this.name}`,
    this.value + uom
  );
  //const label = labels[Array.from(rangeSliders).indexOf(this)];
  //label.textContent = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(3);
}
numberInputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", updateProp);
  //labels[index].textContent = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(3);
});

// measure (line length)
let observeMeasure = new ResizeObserver(function (mutations) {
  const sizeInRem =
    mutations[0].contentRect.width /
    parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    '--_typecsset-text-measure',
    sizeInRem + 'rem'
  );

  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  input.value = sizeInRem;
});
let drag = document.querySelector(".resizable");
observeMeasure.observe(drag);
```

```css
/* globals */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:not(main p) {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:where(html) {
  --_typecsset-body-fontSize: var(--typecsset-base-fontSize, 1rem);
  --_typecsset-body-lineHeight: var(--typecsset-base-lineHeight, 1.5);
  --_typecsset-color-dark: var(--typecsset-color-dark, hsl(0, 0%, 0%));
  --_typecsset-color-light: var(--typecsset-color-light, hsl(0, 0%, 100%));
  --_typecsset-color-neutral: var(--typecsset-color-neutral, hsl(0, 0%, 50%));
  --_typecsset-recursive-caslAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-caslAxis,
    "CASL" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis,
    "CRSV" 0.5
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-monoAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-monoAxis,
    "MONO" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-slntAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-slntAxis,
    "slnt" 0
  );
  --_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis,
    "wght" 400
  );
  --_typecsset-text-measure: var(--typecsset-text-measure, 80rem);
  font-variation-settings: var(--_typecsset-recursive-monoAxis),
    var(--_typecsset-recursive-caslAxis), var(--_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis),
    var(--_typecsset-recursive-crsvAxis), var(--_typecsset-recursive-slntAxis);
  font-family: Recursive, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--_typecsset-color-light);
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-dark);
}

/* dark mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--_typecsset-color-dark);
    color: var(--_typecsset-color-light);
  }
}

main {
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-size: var(--_typecsset-body-fontSize);
  line-height: var(--_typecsset-body-lineHeight);
}

/* elements */
h2,
h4,
input,
main {
  padding-left: 0.2rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.2rem !important;
}

input {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  line-height: 0.9 !important;
}

h2,
h4 {
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral) !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

h2 {
  /* 'cap' unit for capital letters. Safari's jank. */
  letter-spacing: 0.06cap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  --_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis: var(
    --typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis,
    "wght" 600
  );
  font-variation-settings: var(--_typecsset-recursive-wghtAxis);
}

/* sub header below inputs/buttons */
h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}

/* drag */
h4 + h4 {
  color: currentColor !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

input {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  border-top: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-bottom: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border: 1.618px solid var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* box-shadow: inset 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 var(--_typecsset-color-neutral) */
  padding: ;
}

/* blockquote inside main */
blockquote {
  hanging-punctuation: first last;

  &::before {
    content: "\201C";
  }

  &::after {
    content: "\201D";
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
  }
}

/* layout primitives */

.center {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-inline: auto;
  max-inline-size: var(--_typecsset-text-measure);
  padding-inline-start: 1rem;
  padding-inline-end: 1rem;
}

.cluster {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--space, 0.618rem);
  /* use scale */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-ruler {
  background-image: url("icons.svg#icon-ruler-view");
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 3.1rem 1rem;
}

.rhythm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

[class^="rhythm"] > * {
  margin-block: 0;
}

.rhythm-xs > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.2rem;
}

.rhythm-s > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.309rem;
}

.rhythm-m > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 0.618rem;
}

.rhythm-l > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 1.236rem;
}

.rhythm-xl > * + * {
  margin-block-start: 1.857rem;
}

/* utils */
.typeface-alegreya {
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
}

.color\:neutral {
  color: var(--_typecsset-color-neutral);
}

.cursor\:crosshair {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.resizable {
  resize: inline;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.width\:100\% {
  width: 100% !important;
}

/*debugger */
* {
  outline: cornflowerblue dotted 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<body class="center">

  <nav class="rhythm-m">

    <section class="resizable">
      <label class="rhythm-xs">
        <h2>Measure</h2>
        <input id="measure" class="width:100% icon-ruler steppers-none" type="number" value="80" step="1" min="10" max="150" data-uom="rem" name="typecsset-text-measure">
        <div class="cluster">
          <h4>rem</h4>
          <h4>drag&nbsp;&searr;&nbsp;</h4>
        </div>
      </label>
    </section>
  </nav>

  <main class="typeface-alegreya">
    <p>
    <blockquote>The density of texture in a written or types<span title="45th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span>et page is called it<span title="66th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span>s <em>color</em>.<span title="75th character" class="color:neutral cursor:crosshair">&brvbar;</span> This has nothing to do with red or green ink; it refers only to the darkness or blackness of the letterforms in mass. Once the demands of legibilty and logical order are satisfied, <em>eveness of color</em> is the typographer's normal aim. And color depends on four things: the design of the type, the spacing between the letters, the spacing between the words, and the spacing between the lines. None is independent of the others.</blockquote>
    </p>
    <p>
    <blockquote>Anything from <em>45 to 75</em> characters is widely regarded as a satisfactory length of line for a single-column page set in a serifed text face in a text size. The 66-character line (counting both letters and spaces) is widely regarded as ideal. For multiple column work, a better average is 40 to 50 characters.</blockquote>
    </p>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: Thank you. How can I have it in rems like the number input (80) and have the drag and number input bind together so the drag updates the number (rem) in the input?

Comment: Possibly using contentBoxSize with inlineSize?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/contentBoxSize#inlinesize

Comment: @randomname I updated my answer to show you. To convert from px to rem you need to first query for the root font size via `getComputedStyle` since this is something that can be changed via the accessibility settings of the browser or a CSS styling for the document `html` element.

Comment:  Yay! Got it working (updated pen: https://codepen.io/timpish/pen/abMdBay). Threw a toFixed() on there for single decimal.
You are correct. I need the draggable element to sync with the input value change…

Comment: I thought maybe putting --_typecsset-text-measure on .resizable might do it. Nope.

Comment: @randomname I would just update the element's width with an event listener, similar to when you update the CSS variable. You can use `drag.style.width = newWidth`

Comment: You have too much confidence in me! I'm a designer by training and am really trying to tlearn to prototype in code!

I had a width:100% utility class on #measure becasue that input has an SVG background to make it look like a ruler. That was janking things up so I replaced that with inline-size: var(--_typecsset-text-measure);.

I've refactored the JS in the pen a bit but am not sure WHERE the event listener goes? Interestingly, when you first load the page and manipulate the input, the width just works. It's not until *after* you use the drag and go back to the input does it go haywire.

Comment: I've rewritten everything from scratch to make it more clear and more functional (see answer posted below) but I'm still blocked on this scenario:

Steps:
1. Resize measure with the draggable handle
2. Then resize measure via input

Result: everythng BUT #text-measure-resize and #text-measure-rem resizes!